# Function call in C using & in front of argument

Tags: c

```
calc(mesh, prob_data, &cells_fd[crr], species, cr);
```

I'm looking at a function call in a code, and I just wanted to verify if I am looking this correct. In the above call, I am interested in the argument cells_fd[crr]. 
Does the "&" in front of the argument mean that cells_fd[crr] is being passed into the function calc, and whatever calc does, will be stored back inside cells_fd[crr]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cells_fd[crr]` is equivalent to `*(cells_fd + crr)`, and thus `&cells_fd[crr]` is equivalent to  `&*(cells_fd + crr)` which is `(cells_fd + crr)` as the dereference and address operators cancel out.

Thus, your interpretation is correct in that `&cells_fd[crr]` passes the address of `cells_fd[crr]`, so that `calc()` may overwrite the contents, but what `calc()` actually does with the address is not clear from that single line of code without further context.

Answer (score 0):

"&" it's mean you pass the pointer to call function

i don't know what data type is cells_fd[crr]

```
#include "stdio.h"
void call( int * i ){
  int iValue = *i; //retrieve value saved in pointer
  int iResult = iValue * 1000; //any calc

  *i = iResult; //save new value in pointer
}

int main(){
  int i = 123;
  printf("initial value: %d\n", i);
  call( &i );
  printf("value after: %d\n", i);
  return 0;
}
```